# Why does Thana in “Ms. 45” decide to move some body parts from the refrigerator to an unrefrigerated closet?

Tags: plot-explanation, ms-45

In Abel Ferrara’s film [*Ms. 45*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082776/) (1981) Thana — the main protagonist — kills a rapist in her apartment, dismembers the body, places the body parts in garbage bags and then places the body parts in her, now emptied, refrigerator.

[image: Thana shoving body parts in plastic bags in her refrigerator.]

A running thread in the film is how each day she takes one of those bags and discards them in various places in NYC so as to slowly dispose of the rapist’s body.

But as the film progresses, something odd happens: As she nears the end of the body disposal process—and gets ready to toss the last few bags—she first takes one of the bags and shoves it into an unrefrigerated hallway closet and locks it closed:

[image: Thana shoving a bag with a body part in the hallway closet.]

And then goes to her fire escape, opens the window and proceeds to take two other bags with her out the fire escape instead of the front door.

[image: Thana leaving via the fire escape with two other bags.]

##### Why did she shove that one bag of body parts in the unrefrigerated hallway closet and lock it?

I understand she has a nosy neighbor/landlord with a barking dog that bugs her every time she leaves the front door of the apartment so it makes sense to me she would want to sneak out through the fire escape. But the body part in the unrefrigerated hallway closet doesn’t seem to make any sense to me.